# svn: E155016: The file 'xxxxx' has no checksum

Tags: macos, svn, terminal

I got error when execute 'svn upgrade'.
I had used svn 1.6 in Mac OS Lion. And i updated to Mac OS Mountain Lion few days ago. 
so i have to upgrade svn.

I usually use Terminal application and execute svn command in CUI.

when i execute 'svn update'

> $ svn update
>  svn:
>   E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command svn: E155036: Working
>   copy 'xxxxx' is too old
>   (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6)

when i execute 'svn upgrade'

> $ svn upgrade
>   ... 
>   Upgraded
>   'aaaaa'
>   Upgraded
>   'bbbbb'
>   Upgraded
>   'ccccc'
>   Upgraded
>   'ddddd'
>   svn: E155016: This working copy is corrupt and cannot be upgraded.
>   Please check out a new working copy. svn: E155016: The file
>   'eeeee'
>   has no checksum

BY the way, the error file has Japanese Character in file name.
Maybe this is cause.

So How should i resolve this problem? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've switched from 1.6 to 1.7 or 1.8.  You don't mention where you got your copy of svn 1.6 you're using but it's possible you were using one that was patched with the fix for the unicode composition issue.  Specifically there is a patch that's floating around that's in common usage but hasn't been applied to the project as a whole since it is not a complete solution.  I'm not sure if Japanese would run into these problems since I don't know much about Japanese but it seems plausible.

I'd suggest that you create a new checkout from the working copy with your new Subversion client.  I'm not sure if there is a good way to recover from this situation.  In particular I'm not sure if the patch is capable of ensuring that svn upgrade executes properly.

On the other hand this might have nothing to do with the unicode issues on OS X and your working copy might just have been corrupted in a way that didn't turn up until recently.  The upgrade command needs to touch everything in order to convert from the old flat file system to sqlite.  So it often turns up corrupted working copies.  It's usually not worth the effort to try to debug the corruption when you can do a new checkout.

If you have uncommitted changes you want to preserve in your working copy I'd suggest that you checkout the same revision(s) of the contents of your working copy with the new version.  You ought to be able to figure out the version with an old 1.6 svnversion command or by manual inspection of the .svn/entries files.  Once you've done that, rsync the contents of the old working copy over the new working copy while ignoring the .svn directories.  Then run an svn update.  If you don't get the versions of the working copy checkout exactly right you might have some additional issues when you run update.  But hopefully you don't have too many uncommitted changes to clean up.

Alternatively you can try installing a 1.6 copy of Subversion and seeing if you can diff your changes out and determine the correct versions.  But I'm not sure what the state of the working copy databases will be during an interrupted upgrade.  This might be the best way to go since I believe we're really careful about not botching things.

Comment: Thank you. For now, i've checkout again and merged sources. and succeed to commit.